# Request entity too large importing replica schema changes?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.2, map-service, geoprocessing-service, replication

setup:
Main server: SDE 10.2 SQL Server on our own network. Parent replica and tools run from here.
Destination server: Amazon web server running ArcGIS Server & SDE 10.2 SQL Server. Child replica lives here. Accessed through a geodata service

Getting an unusual error trying to sync replica changes from a replica change file to a replica using a geodata service. I generated the change file no problem using the same geodata service but when I use it in the "Import Replica Schema" geoprocessing tool the job fails with an error that says "request entity too large".

Google searches show a similar Apache error to do with max upload file size but this change file is very modest 52 kb.

Has anybody come across something similar?

One thing of note the web service is an Amazon AWS server and it is a 2 way replica.

For the moment I'm going to try to copy the change file to the web server and run the import from there but long term I need to set up batch jobs that test for and import schema changes.

---

Using the replica schema change file directly on the amazon server using .sde connections instead of the geodata service worked without problem

---

I was able to replicate this issue with 2 other replicas created on the same server and published on the same amazon server.